# How to run a parameterized Selenium test with NUnit on TeamCity?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, selenium-webdriver, teamcity

I am writing Selenium webdriver tests in Visual Studio, using C#. These are basically regression tests. The framework that I have chosen in NUnit.

I want to parameterize the URL, so the same tests can be run against different deployments in TeamCity. How do I do that? Should I create a Console Application and then pass an argument to Main()? In that case how do I run the tests from NUnit GUI?

Is any other Framework better than NUnit?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this at test level or test fixture level? As in, do each individual test have different URL's or each individual test fixture have different URL's (i.e all the tests in that particular fixture are using that URL)?

Answer (score 1):

hey here are some useful links which might help answering your question:

http://codewandering.blogspot.com.au/2008/11/regression-testing-for-any-web.html

http://kristjansson.us/?p=947

Additionally you can use environment variables configured in teamcity against the build (so in nightly you might have a different url from a dev build etc)
and call the variable in your source code:

```
public static string GetBaseUrl()
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("testurl")) ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseurl"] : System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("testurl");
}
```

in the code sniplet above, I check to see if i've got the environment and if not, use the appconfig as a backup.

within TeamCity, you set the variables under each configuration:

Edit Config > Build Params > add Environment Variables > select Environment Variables as Kind (env.testurl in my example).
note, when calling this value within C# i don't include the **env.** section from the TeamCity variable name.

Answer (score 0):

We start with a default App.config with values set for running tests locally, for development. Then we have TeamCity swap out the App.config, in a build step, with other config files for different builds.  That's how you can have different settings for different builds, such as target URL.